# Can someone suggest me a way to reduce the number of functions in my Calculator code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This is my XAML code-

```
<Window x:Class="CalculatorGridTrial.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CalculatorGridTrial"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="operationxml"  Grid.Row="0"     Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text= "{Binding Path=Display}" />
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="resultxml" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="{Binding Path=Display}"/> 
    <Button x:Name="numberonexml"  Content="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Click="numberonexml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numbertwoxml" Content="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="numbertwoxml_Click"   />
    <Button x:Name="numberthreexml" Content="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Click="numberthreexml_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="numberfourxml" Content="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Click="numberfourxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numberfivexml" Content="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  Click="numberfivexml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numbersixxml" Content="6" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  Click="numbersixxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numbersevenxml" Content="7" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Click="numbersevenxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numbereightxml" Content="8" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Click="numbereightxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numberninexml" Content="9" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Click="numberninexml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="numberzeroxml" Content="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  Click="numberzeroxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="pointxml" Content="." Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Click="pointxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="clearxml" Content="C" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Click="clearxml_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="plusxml" Content="+" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Click="plusxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="minusxml" Content="-" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Click="minusxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="mulxml" Content="*" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Click="mulxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="divxml" Content="/" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Click="divxml_Click"  />
    <Button x:Name="equalxml" Content="=" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="equalxml_Click"  /> 
</Grid>
```

This is my C# code. Its been only a few days since I have started coding. I am new to this world and have a lot to learn. I have gone through the concept of data binding and implemented it in this code. Can someone help me in creating lesser number of functions. I was thinking if we can create 1 function for all the number functions and 1 for all the operators.

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CalculatorGridTrial
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public class CalculatorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string display;

    public string Display
    {
        get
        {
            return display;
        }
        set
        {

            if(display!= value)
            {
                display = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Display");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CalculatorViewModel calc = new CalculatorViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        operationxml.DataContext = calc;

    }

    List<double> NumbersList = new List<double>();


    List<char> OperatorsList = new List<char>();


    List<string> BufferList = new List<string>();




    char operation;

    string bufferNumber = " ";

    double total = 0;
    private void numberonexml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "1";

        bufferNumber = "1";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numbertwoxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "2";

        bufferNumber = "2";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numberthreexml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "3";

        bufferNumber = "3";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numberfourxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "4";

        bufferNumber = "4";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numberfivexml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "5";

        bufferNumber = "5";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numbersixxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "6";

        bufferNumber = "6";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numbersevenxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "7";

        bufferNumber = "7";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numbereightxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "8";

        bufferNumber = "8";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numberninexml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "9";

        bufferNumber = "9";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void numberzeroxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "0";

        bufferNumber = "0";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void pointxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += ".";

        bufferNumber = ".";

        BufferFunction(bufferNumber);
    }

    private void clearxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display = null;
        NumbersList.Clear();
        OperatorsList.Clear();
        BufferList.Clear();
    }

    private void plusxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "+";

        operation = '+';
        OperatorsFunction(operation);
    }

    private void minusxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "-";

        operation = '-';
        OperatorsFunction(operation);
    }

    private void mulxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "*";

        operation = '*';
        OperatorsFunction(operation);
    }

    private void divxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calc.Display += "/";

        operation = '/';
        OperatorsFunction(operation);
    }



    private void equalxml_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        calc.Display += "=";

        total = NumbersList[0];

        //List<double> TempBufferList2 = BufferList.ConvertAll(s => double.Parse(s));
        //NumbersList.AddRange(TempBufferList2);//Adding the last element(i.e. before '=' to the numberlist
        NumbersList.Add(ConvertBufferArrayToNumber());

        var operatorswitch = ' ';

        for(int loopvariable = 1; loopvariable < NumbersList.Count; loopvariable++)
        {
            operatorswitch = OperatorsList.ElementAt(loopvariable - 1);
            switch(operatorswitch)
            {
                case '+': total += NumbersList.ElementAt(loopvariable); break;
                case '-': total -= NumbersList.ElementAt(loopvariable); break;
                case '*': total *= NumbersList.ElementAt(loopvariable); break;
                case '/': total /= NumbersList.ElementAt(loopvariable); break;

            }
        }

        calc.Display = Convert.ToString(total);
        NumbersList.Clear();
        OperatorsList.Clear();

    }


    private void OperatorsFunction(char operation)
    {

        OperatorsList.Add(operation);//Adding operation to Operatorslist
        //var number = Convert.ToDouble(String.Join("", BufferList));
        NumbersList.Add(ConvertBufferArrayToNumber());

    }

    public void BufferFunction(string bufferNumber)
    {

        BufferList.Add(bufferNumber);// Adding numbers to Bufferlist in string format

    }

    private double ConvertBufferArrayToNumber()
    {
        var number = Convert.ToDouble(String.Join("", BufferList));
        BufferList.Clear();
        return number;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need separate event handlers for each button. Create a single one. You might do as follows..

1. parse the sender of event handler as button..
2. Get the content
3. Parse it to number
4. If not number check for other operators..
5. After getting the result you can continue with your code.. Which is already present

Comment: @Patrick Hofman -  Sure .. I will remember ..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Patrick. I created an Operator function for all the operators and added this line which works like a charm.  var operatorInserted = Convert.ToChar(((Button)sender).Content) ;

Comment: His name is Satyaki. I just edited his answer @bho

Comment: Thanks Satyaki and Patrick. I appreciate both of your help. Cheers!